# How to convert from .avi container to .mp4

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion, libav

I have an `.avi` file containing the following streams:

```
Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile), yuv420p, 608x256 [PAR 1:1 DAR 19:8], 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc

Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
```

I want to play this movie on an Iphone supposed to support mpeg4 video streams as stated [in a previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535836/video-file-formats-supported-in-iphone). For now, I don't care about the audio stream (mp3 doesn't seem to be supported by the Iphone)

As a consequence I am looking for a way to just convert the "container" format of my file from `.avi` to `.mp4` required by the Iphone. Is it doable, and if yes how should I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably should add the way to do that with `avconv` as well:

```
avconv -i input.avi -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

If you are compiling `libav` from source to do that, you need to make sure that you have enabled mp4 muxer. You can do that with

```
./configure [your other options] --enable-muxer=mp4
```

It normally is enabled by default anyhow, but i'm providing it here in case you are using `--disable-everything` or `--disable-muxers` somewhere in the regular options.

Answer (score 6):

Using `ffmpeg`, it is easy to only change the container format, and only [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the all its streams without reencoding:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -map 0 -codec copy output.mov
```

If you specify the `.mov` extension, you can omit `-f mov`, because `ffmpeg` guesses it from the extension. If you really want to remove some streams, check the `-map` option and read about the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use mencoder

Read more here: [Encoding video for iPhone with mencoder](http://blog.jharding.org/2008/05/encoding-video-for-iphone-with-mencoder.html)

Comment: at least could you make the effort to explain why you downvote my answer? this is something which have been explained in details already in the linked article ...

Comment: Op did not insisted on "avoid resampling/re-encoding"
Want to change format, so the iPhone will play it.
Well, not every container format / stream encodings can work.
If you want to get something working, you must match the required format and encodings ...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
ffmpeg -y -i %INFILE% -vcodec mpeg4 -r 65535/2733 -vb 600k -acodec libvo_aacenc -ac 1 -ab 94000 -ar 16000 -s 480x320 %OUTFILE%.new.mp4
```

It's taken from a DOS batch script so you may need to update the variables a little.

The screen resolution is optimised for my phone so my may need to change that as well. Or you can just leave it out.

The -vb is the video bitrate. I don't need superfast video so I often scale it down to this value. Again, you can leave this out if you wish.

Comment: -1 - the OP implied he wanted to avoid resampling/re-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

This re-encodes your video with h.264, but it should work on all iphones.

Comment: -1 - the OP implied he wanted to avoid resampling/re-encoding.